# Qt - Problems with Breakpoints in dynamic library

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

Unfortunately, my breakpoints in the dlls do not work reliably. A breakpoint in a function of the class, which is provided as a dll, is recognized without problems. However, if I have a breakpoint in the base class of this dll, this unfortunately does not work.
If the function is overwritten and the function of the base class is called there, then the breakpoint, which is in the dll class, is not skipped.
So all functions which are not called directly in the dll class but out of it and are in another class will be ignored by the debugger.

Information:
Qt Creator 5.0.2
Based on Qt 5.15.2 (MSVC 2019, 64 bit)
Microsoft Visual C++Compiler 16.10.31424.327(amd64)
CDB-Debugger

Comment: `then the breakpoint, which is in the dll class, is not skipped.` why breakpoint should be skipped? If breakpoints are hit and you expected they are not triggered, this means you have bug in a code. Looks like you are blaming tools for your own mistakes.

Comment: all breakpoints in the dll class are taken into account. But not the breakpoints which are in the baseclass of the dll class. when a put a log output in these functions, the the log is taken into account